# How to put different size of dataset scanario in neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, dataset

I would like to ask the way to put a different number of dataset in neural network.

Here's the toy data.

```
import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

x_train = x_train[:100]
x_test = x_test[:30]

y1 = [*range(30, 0, -1)]
y2 = [*range(40, 0, -1)]
y3 = [*range(10, 0, -1)]
y4 = [*range(20, 0, -1)]

y5 = [*range(13, 0, -1)]
y6 = [*range(17, 0, -1)]


y_train = np.array(y1+y2+y3+y4)
y_test = np.array( y5+y6)
```

I only utilize 130 images from mnist and their are 6 scenarios, 4 scenarios are train dataset, and 2 are test dataset.

training ( 30 ~ 1 40 ~ 1 10~1 20 ~1 ) test ( 13 ~ 1 17 ~1)

My question is is there a way to input each dataset every epoch (x1,y1), ... , (x6,y6)? The length of each scario has different dataset size, for example (x1,y1) would be 30 and the length of (x6,y6) would be 17.

If I have a simple CNN like below, how could I change model (or dataset) to put 6 scenario independently?

Here's the toy model.

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, name="predictions", activation = 'linear')(x2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer =  tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

# Compile a model.
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = 'mse' )

# fit 
history  = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose =2)
```